# Como aplicar 2 mascara na mesma textbox windows form c#

Tags: c#, winforms

Estou com 2 `checkbox` pessoa física e pessoa jurídica, e apenas um `textbox`.

Quero ao selecionar no `checkbox` pessoa física, quero aplicar a mascara para CPF, ou ao selecionar o pessoa jurídica ele aplique a mascara para CNPJ no `textbox`.

Não sei aplica a mascara de acordo com o que seleciono.

Comment: No click do checkbox você verifica qual é e muda a máscara do textbox,: `Textbox1.Mask = "máscara";`

Comment: use `RadioButton` para isso

Comment: Desculpe, não percebi que era Windows Forms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Semanticamente falando, seria correto utilizar *radio button* no lugar de *checkboxes*, já que o usuário só pode marcar uma das opções.

De qualquer forma, a implementação é exatamente a mesma:

No evento de *checked changed* do elemento que define o tipo de pessoa (o *checkbox*) você deve fazer algo assim

```
private void rbPessoaFisica_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtDocumento.Mask = rbPessoaFisica.Checked ? @"000\.000\.000\-00" : @"00\.000\.000\/0000\-00";
}
```

Veja funcionando abaixo

[image: Máscara dinâmica funcionando]

Comment: Obrigado, resolveu meu problema, eu estava usando um `TextBox`, ao invés de usar um `MaskedTextBox`, quando eu fazia `txtCpfCnpj.Mask` mostrava um erro de referência, então troquei de `TextBox` para `MaskedTextBox`, ai eu conseguir aplicar a mascara de acordo com o que eu seleciono no `checkbox`. Agradeço a ajuda!!!

Comment: LINQ, o que você usou pra capturar um gif animado?

Comment: @RicardoPontual [ScreenToGif](http://www.screentogif.com/)